# Chart won't draw. Returning a string value not a Number value - Meteor - Chartjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor, push, chart.js

So I'm trying to build a pie chart using chartjs in meteor.

I'm pretty sure the problem is that the order of precedence is talking over here.

I need the object in this order

```
{
    value: 900.65,
    color:"#red",
    highlight: "#FF5A5E",
    label: "income"
}
```

but i get it in this order

```
{
    color: "#red"
    highlight: "#FF5A5E"
    label: "income"
    value: 900.65
}
```

This is my loop

```
    function drawExpPie(){
  data = [];
  var Task = Tasks.find({},{fields:{value:1,text:1}}).fetch();
  for(var i = 0; i < Task.length; i++)  {
    var newdataset = {
      label:Task[i].text,
      highlight: "#FCA456",
      color: "red",
      value:Task[i].value,
      };
    data.push(newdataset);
  }
  console.log(data);
  var context = document.getElementById('myExpChart').getContext('2d');
  var myPieChart = new Chart(context).Pie(data);
}

Template.exp.helpers({
  exp: function() {return Session.get("exp");}
});

Template.exp.rendered = function(){
  drawExpPie();
};
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Any error that leads you to thinking about precedence?

Comment: objects in javascript do not have any guaranteed order. Also your two objects have different field values. Is there an array you are talking about but not showing? I'm very confused. Also your for loop couldn't produce the first object (different values).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'll add a little more code

Comment: Property order doesn't matter. What's the actual problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: My problem is that my pie chart won't draw unless I put the array inside the for loop. The problem then is that if I do that I only end up with one object. because the array is reset each iteration

Comment: @techn3rd  There is no way to get an object whose property is sorted as you want, if you use something like `for in` to traverse an object, you would find that **different browser has different implementations**.

Comment: If your `data` variable is actually an array, then `data.push()` will *not* "reset" the array. It will append to the end of the array each time. There has to be something you're misunderstanding, or something you're not showing us. Also I'll reiterate the other comments about the order of properties within an object: it just doesn't matter. If you write code where the order *does* matter, such as a `for`-`in` loop, you're most likely doing it wrong. And certainly code like chart.js will not rely on the order of properties within an object.

Comment: It does matter because chartjs requires the object to be in the required format. I have added more code. hopefully that helps.

Comment: @TotalShaw and others: Actually, all modern browsers *do* preserve the order in which you add properties to an object in the typical case where you have non-numeric keys, and in fact this behavior has been codified in the latest JavaScript standard. But of course a library like chart.js is very unlikely to rely in this, as it would access properties by name like `obj.color` etc.

Comment: I refuse to believe that chart.js relies on the order of properties within an object. No professional JavaScript library behaves that way. Of course it relies on the specific property *names*, but not their order - that would be madness.

Comment: According to chart.js documentation, a Pie chart requires a `color` and `value` property for each object in the array passed in. The order of those properties doesn't matter - you target `color` and `value` for the given object in the array. The example shows it in that order, but the actual order is irrelevant. The comments here are correct. http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#doughnut-pie-chart

Comment: That might be true, if the array is in the loop it will draw but it will only have one object. if I put it where it is in my code sample i can console.log every object in data but it won't draw

Comment: Your loop looks fine. `data` should end up with the same number of elements as `Task`. Perhaps `Task` only has one element: what is the value of `Task.length`? Also, as a suggestion you might try `console.log(JSON.stringify(data,null,4))` to get a more clear picture of what's in `data`.

Comment: You mean if you declare `var data =[];` inside the `for` loop? Yes, then it's scoped to the loop, gets reset each time & disappears. If it doesn't draw w/the array *outside* the loop (it should) there's some other error. Regardless, the order of object properties isn't the problem. Anything in your console? Ignoring the pie chart for the moment, what is displayed when you `console.log(data)`?

Comment: in my code sample where the console.log is i get every object in the array.

Comment: BTW the code inadvertently makes `data` a global variable. This could be messing things up, depending on what else the code does. It should be `var data = [];`.

Comment: I've change to var..

this is what i get in the console [
Object
color: "red"
highlight: "#FCA456"
label: "Living"
value: 350.56
__proto__: Object
__defineGetter__: function __defineGetter__() {
__defineSetter__: function __defineSetter__() {
__lookupGetter__: function __lookupGetter__() {
__lookupSetter__: function __lookupSetter__() {
constructor: function Object() {
hasOwnProperty: function hasOwnProperty() {
isPrototypeOf: function isPrototypeOf() {
propertyIsEnumerable: function propertyIsEnumerable() {
toLocaleString: function toLocaleString() {
toString: ..
valueOf: function valueOf() {

Comment: that's for each object.

Comment: If it helps at all I get this in the c9 console. Exception from sub pie id 8QbwtyGFpnbdmzmJw Error: Publish function returned an array of non-Cursors
I20150910-02:20:32.393(0)?     at [object Object]._.extend._runHandler (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:997:1) ....

Comment: Any `value` undefined? Ok, so if it drew the "last" pie section fine inside the loop but throws this error otherwise, one of the previous `value`s in data may be undefined or not a number. Beyond that, not sure...

Comment: The only practical thing for you to do at this point is create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that demonstrates the problem. You don't need Meteor, you can just provide canned test data. Otherwise we're all just guessing. In fact, in the process of creating a fiddle you may well discover what the problem is yourself. Or if not, someone will be able to see the problem easily once they can look at running code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Comment: @Michael Geary I believe it would be pointless making a fiddle as it doesn't support meteor.

Comment: You don't need Meteor to make a fiddle. Call `JSON.stringify(Task)` after you assign the `Task` variable in your Meteor code, and use the resulting JSON object as the source data for your fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Michael Geary.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it...

```
    for(var i = 0; i < Task.length; i++)  {
    data.push({
      label: Task[i].text,
      highlight: "#FF5A5E",
      color:"#F7464A",
      value: Number(Task[i].value)
      });
  }
```

Keynote : value: Number(Task[i].value) would likely work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Change `value:Task[i].value` to

```
 value:Task[i].value || 0,
```

Comment: I tried that, no dice. I also tried label:Task[i].text || " ",